# Stuck running CodeSourcery under Ubuntu

Tags: microcontroller, linux

I installed CodeSourcery on Ubuntu Linux and am a little bit stuck: PATH is OK but the program does not appear on the dashboard or software centre. Maybe it is something within Ubuntu I should change but I do not know how.

Comment: Exactly what version of Codesourcery did you install...was it the free version? What do you mean by "the program" as there are many, many executable programs in Codesourcery.

Comment: Pretty OT.  This is an OS issue

Comment: No, it is an expectation issue.

Comment: Summary, it is an issue :-)

Comment: Yes he wants to eventually use this for microcontroller development, but this particular issue has nothing to do with our site as far as I can tell... I suggest either the Ubuntu SE site, or StackOverflow

Comment: This question comes from a trivial but near total misunderstanding of what the toolchain is - it has nothing to do with which of the various host operating systems it is running on.  Progressing towards actually accomplishing anything, the point where the other sites would be insufficient will quickly be reached.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no gui component to this toolchain (or none worth paying attention to), just command line executables such as

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc
arm-none-eabi-ld
arm-none-eabi-objdump
```

etc, or different prefix names depending on which one you installed.

You could type long and cryptic commands using these to build, examine, or debug programs manually.  Most however automate the process by creating a Makefile for their program, or configuring an IDE to run the toolchain components in the needed way.

If you are using an IDE, that is what you might launch from a menu, but sooner or later you will find yourself needing to do some things from the command line.